# How to get text inside tag using python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get text (example text) inside tags using beautiful soup
The html structure looks like this:

```
...
<div>
       <div>Description</div>
       <span>
          <div><span>example text</span></div>
       </span>
    </div>
...
```

What i tried:

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
desc = soup.find('div.div.span.div.span')
print(str(desc))
```

Comment: try `desc.text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong.

```py
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = '''\
... <div>
...        <div>Description</div>
...        <span>
...           <div><span>example text</span></div>
...        </span>
...     </div>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
>>> desc = soup.select_one('div span div span')
>>> desc.text
'example text'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `.find()` with multiple tag names in it stacked like this. You need to repeatedly call `.find()` to get desired result. Check out [**docs**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) for more information. Below code will give you desired output:

```
soup.find('div').find('span').get_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
desc = soup.find('div').find('span')
print(desc.getText())
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out -

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('''<div>
       <div>Description</div>
       <span>
          <div><span>example text</span></div>
       </span>
    </div>''',"html.parser")

text = soup.span.get_text()
print(text)
```